# How to enforce specific date format in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table that contains records, with a DATETIME column. I am writing a stored proc that will take a startTime and endTime and return all records between these two times. I want to force users to provide the time in a specific format ('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnn'). The reason being I don't my table contains a lot of records, and I don't want to limit the data retrieval to two points in time during the same day only (so they must provide times to a seconds granularity at least).

Is there anyway to enforce this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but then you have to take the parameters as strings (varchar) instead of datetime, as the datetime values `2010-12-08` and `2010-12-08 00:00:00.000` are the same.

You can verify that the length of the input strings meet the requirement, and then convert them to datetime using `convert(datetime, startTime, 126)`.

Comment: But then do I not lose language-neutrality if I accept varchars?

Answer (score 1):

You can force specific format only if you're accepting string as date - then, you could try to parse that string with your format and if it fails you throw error.

But, if your stored proc accepts DATETIME variable there's no 'format' - it's simply a variable with value.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like:

```
IF   @arg NOT LIKE    '19[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
 AND @arg NOT LIKE '2[01][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]T[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
RAISERROR('Wrong format', 10, 1)
```

?

Only if `@arg` is passed as a string of course.

Comment: Interresting... 1299 is an accepted year, but not 1300... ;) And my dates generally have monhts and date also, not only year and time.

Comment: @Michel de Ruiter: Missing the separators, so 29991939 is a valid date, but not 2010-12-13...

Comment: @Guffa: fixed again. I don't understand where my head was.

Comment: @Michel de Ruiter: It still accepts the strange year ranges 1000-1199, 1900-2199, 2900-2999...

Answer (score 0):

As long as the users provide *any* valid date format, you should accept it. Learn to use CAST and CONVERT instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx